# How to mask PCI data in the Kinesis appender of log4j?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, amazon-kinesis

I am masking the PCI data in the rolling file of log4j in the similar way of the below post.

https://alesaudate.medium.com/masking-sensitive-data-in-log4j-2-the-simplest-way-possible-2c2e74c17f2d

When the log file created in the server, the sensitive data gets masked. I am forwarding the logs to AWS Kinesis using the Kinesis appender. Example snippet of [Kinesis appender](https://github.com/kdgregory/log4j-aws-appenders/blob/trunk/docs/kinesis.md).

```
    <KinesisAppender name="KINESIS">
    <streamName>logging-stream</streamName>
    <partitionKey>{pid}</partitionKey>
    <batchDelay>500</batchDelay>
    <JsonLayout complete="false" compact="true" eventEol="true" properties="true" locationInfo="true">
         <KeyValuePair key="applicationName" value="${env:APP_NAME}" />
         <KeyValuePair key="environment" value="${sys:deployment:-dev}" />
         <KeyValuePair key="processId" value="${awslogs:pid}" />
         <KeyValuePair key="hostname" value="${awslogs:hostname}" />
         <KeyValuePair key="timestamp" value="$${date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'}" />
   </JsonLayout>
```

When the logs gets redirected to Kinesis, the PCI data is not masked. How to use pattern(converter) in the Kinesis appender like a rolling file?

**Update:**

The converter key that I am using is logMasker.
So, I tried the below key value pair inside JsonLayout.

```
  <KeyValuePair key="message" value="${%logMasker}"/>
  <KeyValuePair key="message" value="${logMasker}"/>
  <KeyValuePair key="message" value='%logMasker'/>
  <KeyValuePair key="message" value=%logMasker/>
```

So far, no luck.

Comment: Please show your actual Log4J configuration (and, preferably, a complete working example). As I noted on the issue that you raised, I wouldn't expect that a plugin designed for `PatternLayout` would work with `JsonLayout`.